# What cause pip did not work after reinstall python?

Tags: python, pip, windows-10

I had Python 3.7.4 in `D:\python3.7.4` before but for some reason, I uninstalled it today, then I changed the folder name to `D:\python3.7.5` and installed python 3.7.5 in it, then, when I try to use pip in cmd I got a `fatal error` saying

> Unable to create processing using '"Unable to create process using '"d:\python3.7.4\python.exe"  "D:\Python3.7.5\Scripts\pip.exe"'

I tried to change all things contain `python3.7.4` in environment variable to `python3.7.5` but the same error still exists, does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to run `python`? And what is the result of `where python`?

Comment: If you're on WIN10 some versions have a bug that doesn't let you change a USERs PATH environment variable, you have to use administrator account if you want to simplify things without having to edit the registry. Might be it. Otherwise just check your PATH and test in the console. You should update PATH to your new install, include both base dir of \python3.7.5 and python3.7.5\scripts. Should fix it.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: The python itself works well, I am sure I change the environment variable with administrator account

Comment: No it's not a virtual environment

Comment: Use `python -m pip` to manage requirements. It avoids confusion as to which python installation pip is modifying. It will always modify the installation of python through which you run the command

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new folder and run the installation there.

This should work, as I did the same myself to go install 2 different versions before